# JavaScript Array null vs [ ]

Tags: javascript, arrays, null

I'm writing a function in JavaScript that:

1. Reads in a JSON
2. If value = null, push null to array.
3. Else, push value to array

So for example if I read in, one-by-one:

```
M, L, XL, and null
```

The returned array should be:

```
[M, L, XL, null]
```

However, every time I do that, I get:

```
[M, L, XL, ""]
```

Or if I read in just a null value (so no M, L, XL, etc at all, just null), then I get:

```
[]
```

I am not certain, but I think this might have something to do with how JavaScript works. Is null equivalent to [] for an array in JavaScript?

I really need to output null in my JSON because the JSON will be read by another file that I have no control of.

#### Current Function:

I am not particularly good at JavaScript, but I think the function should get the job done (minus the []/null part). It also seems a little repetitive, especially the flag part, but filter seems to ignore/remove null if I push it directly in the nested loop.

```
//Results will be stored here
var type1EnumUnique = [];
var type2EnumUnique = [];

function extractCode() {
    var type1Enum = []; 
    var typeEnum = []; 
    //For uniqueFilter() below
    var type1NullFlag = false; 
    var type2NullFlag = false;

    $.each(type1, function (index, value) {
        if (value.code)
            type1Enum.push(value.code);
        else
            type1NullFlag = true;

            $.each(type1[index].type2, function (index, value) {
                if (value.code)
                    typeEnum.push(value.code);
                else
                    type2NullFlag = true;
            });
    });


    //Filter to make array unique
    type1EnumUnique = type1Enum.reverse().filter(uniqueFilter).reverse();
    type2EnumUnique = typeEnum.reverse().filter(uniqueFilter).reverse();
    function uniqueFilter(value, index, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(value, index + 1) === -1;
    }

    //Appending "null" back to array (filter removes/ignores null)
    if (type1NullFlag === true)
        type1EnumUnique.unshift(null);
    if (type2NullFlag === true)
        type2EnumUnique.unshift(null);

}
```

Comment: Could you include the JSON that you read in?

Comment: What is with this `reverse()`?

Comment: You probably want to use `value` instead of `type1[index]`.

Comment: Is `null` the only falsy value you expect for `value.code`?

Comment: Thanks! Reverse() is to sort the array after removing duplicates (is there a better way?), and I'll make the change to "value" instead! 

Null will be one of the few available values for value.code (others just normal strings or numbers, such as M, L, 1, 2, 3).